# How to write module for sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I have just learned sails.js, it is a framework base on NodeJs platform. Website is http://sailsjs.org. Now I want to write a module for it, such as upload a file feature but I wouldn't know where to begin.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but here it goes:

Basically since sails inherits from express then you can use module.exports to add a module.
For example if you create a module named `test` in the `config` folder then you can access it via the `sails` object by writing:

```
sails.config.foo()
```

where foo is a module inside the test file.